# Delta3D Build on android

Tags: android, build, game-engine, xerces-c

anyone knows any information that might help me build Delta3D on android, they say it is platform dependent, but it seems that wither no one ever built it on android or no one shared his experience building it on android, 
well , as for me i have been making the make files by hand till now ( i dont know how to make them other way ) and i have built OSG cause it depends on it, but now i got stuck on building xercesc .... i will share the build process as it gets done ( i promise ^_^ )

please any hints on how to do this will be highly appreciated.

( i would've add Delta3D tag but i am new here so i dont have enough prev. )

Kind regards.